# using lists for storing data inside loop and conversion to np.array

Tags: python, numpy

quite often i do something like:

```
data = []
for i in range(number_of_components):
    d = some calculation (output may change size)
    data.append(d)
data = np.asarray(data)
```

It is very convenient to store the data inside a list. Especially if the data may change it`s size. Quite often I work with numpy arrays and I find it easier when every function returns either an array or a list. So I end up with such constructs. Is there a better solution ?

Comment: What do you mean the output may change size? You can't have a "proper" ragged numpy array, so if the length of `d` varies you will get a numpy array of (list) objects, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the only way this works is if `d` is the same length for all `i` in a given loop (but as you suggest, it can change between loops). I often encounter such a scenario and when memory etc is at a premium, I just create the array on the first call.

Something like:

```
data = None
for i in range(number_of_components):
    d = some calculation()
    if data is None:
        data = np.empty((number_of_components,) + d.shape, d.dtype)

    data[i, ...] = d
```

This certainly avoids a superfluous interim list.